# HEVC: How to modify intra prediction modes in the Encode for steganography purposes?

Tags: c++, hevc

I've been working to to hide data in intra-prediction modes of HEVC.
I successfuly found a point in code where RDO has already completed and the optiomal modes already set into PUs.

When I set new modes the encoder run successfully. But the decoder aborts while decoding the stream complaining that the encoded bit stream is not proper.

What I'm I doing wrong?

----**Edits** -------

@Mosen you are right that in encoding stage, embeding changes may result in to the bit stream been broken.

I then tried to apply changes during the compression stage. I found that changing the modes of luma PUs before YUV samples are not copied and chroma modes not calculated works as expected.

In function: `Void TEncCu::xCheckRDCostIntra`

I made change after function: `m_pcPredSearch->estIntraPredLumaQT(...);` has been called

But before this:

```
m_ppcRecoYuvTemp[uiDepth]->copyToPicComponent(COMPONENT_Y, rpcTempCU->getPic()->getPicYuvRec(), rpcTempCU->getCtuRsAddr(), rpcTempCU->getZorderIdxInCtu() );

  if (rpcBestCU->getPic()->getChromaFormat()!=CHROMA_400)
  {
    m_pcPredSearch->estIntraPredChromaQT( rpcTempCU, m_ppcOrigYuv[uiDepth], m_ppcPredYuvTemp[uiDepth], m_ppcResiYuvTemp[uiDepth], m_ppcRecoYuvTemp[uiDepth], resiLuma DEBUG_STRING_PASS_INTO(sTest) );
  }
```

Unfortunately some changes I make in the modes are get lost in the RDO loop when the encode changes its decision in splitting or not splitting some PUs.

So in the decoder I see many PUs with my embeded modes. But some are not seen (I guess left out after the RDO opting not to split that way anymore due to cost calculations) and some which I have not embed in them anything are also seen in the encoder. (I guess the encoder decided to further split after my changes).

And as a result I cant receive my message at the decoder because some peaces (bits) are missing and some have been inserted

So here I'm stuck again, **how to resist this behavior**?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are modifying decisions at the encoding stage (bitstram writing), while you should do it during RDO.

When a decision is made, it has to be written as is. Because next decisions to be made will depend on it.

Comment: Thanks for your concern and quick reply. That was my guess also. But many are suggesting to do changes for embeding after the decisions are made, i.e in encoding stage not compression. --- I've tried to go in the compression stage and I overcame the binVal error in decoder. But still encountered other problems. I'm editing my question for that.